# PayPal responsive site when doing preauthorization for adaptive payments.

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Does anyone know if paypal has a mobile specific site or responsive site for their classic apis? Currently I am just using a sandbox for testing and they may have one on production. However, when redirecting from my site for pre-authorization for adaptive payments I end up on paypals gigantic checkout page.

Thanks to anyone who can clarify for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i kind of answered my own question. For some reason paypal has added flex to all of the adaptive payment apis. It just simply does not allow it for pre-authorization. Its literally the only one. You can do it for future payment pre-authorization...just not adaptive payaments.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_adaptivepaymentsmobile.pdf

Basically the problem they have is this. All of their flex apis require a paykey. with adaptive payments you may also use a preapproval key. however, to get said preapproval key the user must pre-authorize in a non flex site. The only thing you can do is have them authorize preauthorization for future payments which is not what I need. I need a one time pre-authorization for adaptive payments.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you specifically need Adaptive Payments?  If you use Express Checkout it will automatically switch to a mobile experience when a mobile device is detected.

Comment: Yea. Its for a site doing donations for walkathons. I have to get their per-mile donation and their max donation and have them pre-authorize it and then finalize the payment after the walkathon is completed. So, theres no way of knowing what the final payment will be till several days later after the runner has finished.